# How do I retrieve the contents of a simple alert box that is overflowing beyond the bottom of my screen?

Tags: javascript, alert, innerhtml

In one of my site's functions, I have applied the MathJax API to a string of text. I am now trying to convert that string using the text-to-voice API `meSpeak.js`. I am having a problem with some of the text after the MathJax API transforms it, and I am trying to see ALL of the text and html tags that go with the string (**transformText**) after the MathJax transform. When I try to take the transformed string and then use innerHTML, all I see is the HTML output (no tags, style elements, etc.)

When I try to pass the MathJax-transformed string to a modal alert box I created, I only see the HTML output (since my modal Alert box is really only a fancy div with a high z-index) Only the default alert() shows me all the text/tags/styling. However, there are so many tags and styles applied to MathJax-transformed strings that the default alert box overflows beyond the bottom of the screen:

```
alert(transformText); //contents of default alert box overflow beyond bottom of screen
```

As you probably already know, you can not right/left click nor copy the contents for the in-house alert box (unless this is just me). Is there any way to re-position the default alert box, enable overflow-y:scroll in the default alert box, or somehow otherwise see (or copy) ALL of the MathJax-transformed text/tags/styles for the string **transformText**? Thanks for any help

Comment: Did you try clicking and then CTRL+A  to select all ?

Comment: Use `console.log` to display debugging data, not `alert`

Comment: Can't you simply view the source code and check what is in the alert?

Comment: CTRL+A (at least in Chrome) does not select anything

Comment: I tried viewing the source but nothing regarding the alert is there (in Chrome)

Comment: Don't view the source, but inspect the DOM.

Comment: OK...got it in Firefox